# Dcast with dummy and other functions

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose that I have the following data

```
dt = data.table(customer = c(1,1,1,2), product = c('a','b','c','b'), 
price = c(14.9,17.2,18.4,19.2),tax=c(1.2,1.9,0.4,0.7))

       customer product price tax
    1:        1       a  14.9 1.2
    2:        1       b  17.2 1.9
    3:        1       c  18.4 0.4
    4:        2       b  19.2 0.7
```

Is there a way to combine the two following `dcasts` into a single one

```
> dcast(dt, customer ~ product, value.var = c('price','tax'), fun = sum)
   customer price_a price_b price_c tax_a tax_b tax_c
1:        1    14.9    17.2    18.4   1.2   1.9   0.4
2:        2     0.0    19.2     0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0

> dcast(dt, customer ~ product, fun.aggregate = length)
   customer a b c
1:        1 1 1 1
2:        2 0 1 0
```

or I will need to make two separate calls and merge both by the customer number?

The desired output will be like

```
   customer price_a price_b price_c tax_a tax_b tax_c a b c
1:        1    14.9    17.2    18.4   1.2   1.9   0.4 1 1 1
2:        2     0.0    19.2     0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0 0 1 0
```

Comment: is there any reason why the merge is not preferred? or you can do `dcast(dt, 
    customer ~ product, 
    list(length, sum), value.var=c("price","tax"))` and delete the extra columns

Comment: @chinsoon12 no reason, I do it in SPSS in a single call and was curious if there is way to do it in `r` with `dcast` ... if there is no way to do it currently with `dcast` there is no problem I can use two calls and merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three ways to achieve (or come close to) the desired result with one expression:

#### 1. Join

```
dcast(dt, customer ~ product, sum, value.var = c("price","tax"))[
  dcast(dt, customer ~ product, length), on = "customer"]
```

> ```
>    customer price_a price_b price_c tax_a tax_b tax_c a b c
> 1:        1    14.9    17.2    18.4   1.2   1.9   0.4 1 1 1
> 2:        2     0.0    19.2     0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0 0 1 0
> ```

This comes close to OP's expected result.

#### 2. Lists of `value.var` and `fun.aggregate`

The help page `help("dcast")` says:

> When `value.var` is a list of length equal to `length(fun.aggregate)` each
> element of `fun.aggregate` is applied to each element of `value.var`
> column.

```
dcast(dt, customer ~ product, list(sum, n = length), 
      value.var = list(c("price","tax"), "product"))
```

> ```
>    customer price_sum_a price_sum_b price_sum_c tax_sum_a tax_sum_b tax_sum_c product.1_n_a product.1_n_b product.1_n_c
> 1:        1        14.9        17.2        18.4       1.2       1.9       0.4             1             1             1
> 2:        2         0.0        19.2         0.0       0.0       0.7       0.0             0             1             0
> ```

However, ths requires some tweaking of the column names to achieve OP's expected result:

```
dcast(dt, customer ~ product, list(sum, n = length), 
      value.var = list(c("price","tax"), "product"))[
        , setnames(.SD, stringr::str_remove(names(.SD), "_sum|product.1_n_"))][]
```

> ```
>    customer price_a price_b price_c tax_a tax_b tax_c a b c
> 1:        1    14.9    17.2    18.4   1.2   1.9   0.4 1 1 1
> 2:        2     0.0    19.2     0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0 0 1 0
> ```

#### 3. `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

For the sake of completeness, `tidyr::pivot_wider()` can be applied on `data.table` objects as well:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(dt, names_from = product, 
                   values_from = c(price, tax, product), 
                   values_fn = list(price = sum, tax = sum, product = length), 
                   values_fill = 0)
```

> ```
>   customer price_a price_b price_c tax_a tax_b tax_c product_a product_b product_c
>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>     <int>     <int>
> 1        1    14.9    17.2    18.4   1.2   1.9   0.4         1         1         1
> 2        2     0      19.2     0     0     0.7   0           0         1         0
> ```

Unfortunately, this would require still some tweaking of column names (`product_a`, etc.) to match OP's expected result. And the output has lost its `data.table` attribute.

Comment: thank you for the answer, although the first one requires a `join` it's more clean than the second, because this one needs names corrections.